# How to make compiler infer the right template integer for me

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this piece:

```
template <int N> void fill_with_magic(array<int, N>& whatever){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        whatever[i] = magic(i, N);
    }
}
```

I call it by specific instance so for array of 3 I would have to do:

```
array<int, 3> some_array_of_3;
fill_with_magic<3>(some_array_of_3);
```

But do I really have to write `<3>`? Compiler already knows the array size so theoretically it could of infer the right instance based on that size. Can I really make it do that?

Comment: Remove the explicit argument and try it. It should work.

Comment: A call to fill_with_magic(some_array_of_3) or fill_with_magic<>(some_array_of_3) will work.

Comment: You must declare the non-type parameter with `size_t` for the deduction to work. If a conversion (int -> size_t for N) is involved, no deduction happens.

Comment: Aha! Yes, it's about `size_t`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the deduction of the argument: the second template argument of a `std::array` is not an `int` so the deduction doesn't take place because it requires a conversion.

You should define your method as

```
template <array<int, 0>::size_type N> void fill_with_magic(array<int, N>& whatever){
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    whatever[i] = magic(i, N);
  }
}
```

So that you are correctly expecting a `array<int,0>::size_type` as the argument, which will then be correctly deduced. Actually I think most of the implementation use `size_t` but this should be more portable (unless `std::array<T, 0>` gets a special specialization).

Comment: `size_type` is required to be `size_t`, so using it is portable as well as being simpler.